# RxJS - Convert promise chain to observable not working

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

I'm trying to convert promise chaining:

```
this.tradeTypesLogicService.getList().$promise
    .then(this.filterTradeTypes)
    .then(this.setSelectedTradeType)
```

to an rxjs observable:

```
this.tradeTypesLogicService
    .getList() //returns observable now
    .pipe(mergeMap(this.filterTradeTypes), map(this.setSelectedTradeType))
    .subscribe();



protected filterTradeTypes = (tradeTypes: Array<any>) => {
    this.tradeTypes = filter(tradeTypes, (trade) => {
        if (trade.id === this.mappedItem.tradeTypeId && !trade.isActive) {
            trade.label = trade.label + " (inactive)";
            return true;
        }
        return trade.isActive;
    });
    return this.tradeTypes;
}



public setSelectedTradeType = (tradeTypes): void => {
    this.selectedTradeTypeModel = tradeTypes.find(tt => tt.id === this.mappedItem.tradeTypeId);
}
```

I need to pass the array that is returned from `filterTradeTypes` into `setSelectedTradeType` and it is only passing one item from that array.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but the void method should be passed to tap or subscribe

Comment: @AluanHaddad I need to pass the array that is returned from `filterTradeTypes ` into `setSelectedTradeType` and it is only passing one item from that array.

Comment: I also think you need map instead of mergeMap. The latter will flatten an observable of arrays into an observable of array elements

Comment: I realize that, I was just pointing out another problem that I noticed.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you, using `map` instead of `mergeMap` solved it. Old SO posts about converting promise chains to observables said flatMap/mergeMap are the equivalent of chaining a promise, which lead me to use mergeMap.

Comment: No problem. Those posts aren't actually wrong it's just that promises and observables are very different abstractions in that nested promises collapse. So if you have a promise that returns a promise that returns a promise it just returns a promise. So in actuality, sometimes the translation of `then` is `map` and sometimes it's `mergeMap`. It would be merged map if you were applying a function that returns a promise in `then`

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense... I'm pretty tired.

Comment: Another difference is that mergeMap flattens what it considers higher order structures by one level. These structures include iterables, observables, and Promises